# Fourier cosine series expansion of $f(x)=1$

Tags: fourier-series

> Fourier cosine series expansion of $$f(x)=1,~~~ x\in (0,\pi)$$

Hint is "thought is better than calculation".

Comment: You're tasked with expanding $f$ in terms of $1, \cos x, \cos 2x,\ldots$.

Comment: Correct, but I'm drawing a blank on what to do. I tried normal expansion methods but got nowhere.

Comment: The Fourier series is unique.. You need to represent the $1$ function as a linear combination of $1,\cos x,\cos 2x,\ldots$. What is the *obvious* way to do this?

Comment: So, do I just let the fourier series for cosine equal 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, do I just let the Fourier series for cosine equal $1$?

Yes, the cosine expansion of this function has just one nonzero term: $1$. The rest of coefficients are therefore zero.

This is something that always happens when you expand a vector in a basis which contains that vector. If your basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 
$\{(2,3), (1,-5)\}$, and you want to expand the vector $v=(1,-5)$ in this basis, the expansion is just that:
$$(1,-5) = 0\cdot (2,3)+1\cdot (1,-5)$$

Indeed, this particular choice of coefficients evidently works, and since the coefficients are unique, any other method would produce same ones.

Comment: I think you meant "0", not "9".

Comment: You have a typo, 9 should be 0

Comment: Thank @Idris; you could simply edit it though.